# ¿Cómo crear pruebas para una aplicación de Python que se pondrá en línea?

Tags: python, test, travis-ci

Creé [una aplicación](https://github.com/antoinecomp/moodbot) en python. Intento desplegarla y estoy teniendo problemas. En [Travis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/for-beginners/), una plataforma de integración continua, parece que tenemos que hacer pruebas y nunca he hecho ninguna. Entonces, ¿quería saber qué era y cómo hacer tontos test para mi aplicación en Python para que pueda ser desplegado?

Por lo momento solo hicé `travis.yml`:

```
language: python
rvm:
 - 3.5.2
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
script:
  - py.test
```

Siguiendo el consejo de [usuario], llené app.py de esta manera :

```
echo "No hay tests"
```

Pero de repente en Travais, entonces tengo:

```
0.42s$ py.test
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.14, pytest-3.3.0, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/travis/build/antoinecomp/myflaskapp, inifile:
collected 0 items                                                              
========================= no tests ran in 0.02 seconds =========================
The command "py.test" exited with 5.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

¿Me perdí algo? ¿Debo instalar algo con py.test?

Comment: crear un test que devuelva true en todos los casos? o cambiar donde dice `- py.test` a `- echo "No hay tests"`

Comment: Lo que te decía @aloMalbarez era que modificaras `travis.yml`, no `app.py`. En cualquier caso, eso es un "parche" provisional. Toda aplicación de cierta envergadura debería tener tests "de verdad". No sé qué sentido tiene usar travis sin tests, pues su misión es verificar que pasan correctamente todos.

Comment: je, ahí armé una explicación mas completa.respecto a saltearse los tests o darlos por válido, siendo que recién arranca con travis y no hay tests definidos, el primer test es ver que travis complete el deploy en caso de que no haya errores (test trivial o test 0, que en algunas situaciones ayuda)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El archivo `.travis.yml` es una receta de pasos a seguir para hacer/testear una integración y/o deploy.

En la sección `script:` le decís qué comandos correr para lograr esto y el resultado del comando (si termina con o sin código de error) es lo que marca el build como fallado o exitoso.

Ejemplo de fichero **.travis.yml**:

```
language: python
rvm:
 - 3.5.2
install:
 - pip install -r requirements.txt
script:
 - py.test  # Si este comando da error se marca el build como fallado
            # (igual continúa si hay más comandos)
```

`py.test` (o `pytest`) es una suite de tests para Python.

En caso de querer saltearte el paso de tests puedes usar un fichero `.travis.yml` tipo:

```
language: python
rvm:
 - 3.5.2
install:
 - pip install -r requirements.txt
script:
 - echo "No hay tests"  # 'echo' no da error, sigue el build
```

En caso de querer armar tests, la convención general y mas simple es crear archivos con nombre `test_moduloatestear.py` y dentro de este archivo funciones que empiezan con `test_`

ejemplo:

`app.py`

```
# funcion sumar uno en app

class App:
    def sumaUno(self, x):
        return x + 1

a = App()
print a.sumaUno(3)
```

---

Lo probamos

```
 $ python app.py
 4
```

---

Creamos dos tests uno que pasa y otro que falla (incluyo una función que por el nombre no es tenida en cuenta como test):

`test_app.py`

```
# test_app.py

from app import App

def estaFuncionNoEsUnTestSoloDevuelve5():
    return 5

def test_respuestaCorrecta():
    app = App()
    assert app.sumaUno(4) == 5

def test_respuestaIncorrecta():
    app = App()
    assert app.sumaUno(3) == 5
```

al correr los tests el resultado será:

```
$ py.test

==================== test session starts ===========
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.6.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/code/pyTest, inifile:
collected 2 items 

test_app.py .F                                 [100%]

==================== FAILURES ======================
____________________ test_respuestaIncorrecta ______

    def test_respuestaIncorrecta():
        app = App()
>       assert app.sumaUno(3) == 5
E       assert 4 == 5
E        +  where 4 = <bound method App.sumaUno of <app.App instance at 0xb6a26bac>>(3)
E        +    where <bound method App.sumaUno of <app.App instance at 0xb6a26bac>> = <app.App instance at 0xb6a26bac>.sumaUno

test_app.py:11: AssertionError
===================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.23 seconds =====
```

Este es el setup más básico, en https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#goodpractices podés encontrar esquemas y casos más reales con aplicaciones no tan simples como mi ejemplo.

En el caso de una aplicación Flask hay algunos pasos extra (y ejemplos) que podés ver en http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/tests/.